# Accessing links from JS in a WebBrowser object

Tags: c#, javascript

I need to automate some tasks on a website that does not have an API, and uses a substantial amount of JavaScript, without any graceful fall-back, so is it possible to parse over content added to a page via JS, with C#, I assumed that this would be done with a WebBrowser object but so far I've been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [SWAT](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ulti-swat) or [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/)

Both are unit testing frameworks for automating web site front end testing, but can easily be used to traverse the DOM on a website as you want to do.